# Compactly exploring many combinations of parameters in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

Sometimes I want to run part of my code many times with varying parameters and display the results for easy comparison. For example, suppose I have logical parameters `x`, `y`, and `z`, and I want to compare the output (perhaps a table or plot) of `somefunction(x,y,z)` for each combination of values.

The options I know about for doing this all have drawbacks:

1. Just display each run one after the other. But there may be many parameters with many possible values, and scrolling back and forth is undesirable if you want to specifically jump between multiple outputs that vary only along a single parameter.
2. With shiny, you can make an app with controls for each parameter. This lets you switch back and forth more freely, but shiny is a nonstarter because it's very hard to share shiny apps with non-R-savvy people. Plus, I'd like to put this in an Rmarkdown report.
3. You *can* embed shiny controls in an Rmarkdown document, but then (afaik) you have to have an R session running in the background as part of the document - it's basically a shiny app that looks like an Rmarkdown document. Still can't just send someone an HTML report and trust they can just open it in their browser. Also, overkill because I don't really need a code backend, just a way to switch between already-generated static results at will.
4. Rmarkdown allows you to treat subheadings as tabs (via `{.tabset}`). No code backend needed, just a compact way of viewing static results. This works if I only have one parameter I'm varying. If I have two, I can nest tabset subheadings, but I can't easily switch between the top row of tabs and keep the parameter options the same on the bottom rows.

Ideally, there would be a way to use something like a set of radio buttons or other shiny-style controls in an Rmarkdown document to control what is currently displayed, *without* having to run an R session inside the document. That would mean the logic of the controls would be handled in the html, rather than in R - clearly something that's possible at one level, but I don't know enough html to know if it can be down with multiple levels.

Is it possible to do this?